# How change value of combobox in Delphi Tchromium?

Tags: delphi, tchromium

How can I change value of combobox using Tchromium Delphi?
Version Tchromimum DCEF3

```
<td class="droplabels" nowrap="nowrap">Лист</td>
<td colspan="3">
   <div class="ui-widget">
      <select id="sheet" name="sheet" style="font-size:0.7em;width:761px;" 
         class="form_select" onchange="showSheet(this.value);">
             <option value="1" selected="selected">Account List </option>
             <option value="2">Merchant list</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</td>
```

try this but not worked...

`Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("sheet").selectedIndex=2;', 'about: blank', 0);
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("providerField").onchange();', 'about: blank', 0);`

Comment: Which version of Chromium are you using ?

Comment: Last version from svn/truck

Comment: I meant more if it's [`CEF1`](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) or [`CEF3`](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/) wrapper for Delphi. Could you [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15354828/edit) and include this information into your question, please ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an ExecuteJavascript on it. So you can manipulate everything on it with Javascript.
If you want to change that combobox value , then change it with using DOM.Get its id using "document.getElementById", then change its selectedIndex by accessing its selectedIndex.
But , that'll not triggering onChange event. 
So , you need to call it manually using javascript again.

Here's the code to change it's selectedIndex :

```
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("sheet").selectedIndex='+comboboxIndex+';', 'about: blank', 0);
```

To trigger onChange event manually :

```
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("providerField").onchange();', 'about: blank', 0);
```

Change Chromium1 to your TChromium variable object name.

Here's for more information about Select
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

If you don't know anything about DOM , read it here
http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp
In simple way , you just need to get the DOM object of it then do what you want by accessing and modifying its properties

Sorry for my bad English.
*edited*

Comment: You question is not clear at all. You need to be clear with you problem and what you are looking for should be bit more detailed.

Comment: i think he just want to change the combobox value that appear on the chromium browser. am i wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, but you have to clearly state your assumption and give answer to that. If you can edit the answer and be detailed it will be great

Comment: not worked   Crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("sheet").selectedIndex=4;', 'about: blank', 0);
  crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.getElementById("providerField").onchange();', 'about: blank', 0);

Comment: @Ulugbek did you find anything? I have the same problem.